# Best spellchecker addin to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, spell-checking, visual-studio-addins

I'm looking good (preferably free) add-in to Visual Studio 2010 which is able to **check spelling of my code**
(must analyse  strings and comments, nice to have methods/fields names as well)

Can you advice any?

Answer (score 6):

> Please note:
>
> This is an answer to a question about **Visual Studio 2010**.
>
> The question and answer both date back to 2011.

Try
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce/
It has very good reviews/ratings and so many downloads.

If you deal with ASP.NET most of the time, this one might be even better for you...
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0db4814c-255e-4cc6-a2c2-a428de7f8949?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: Installed tis MS checker but it doesnt work to me. Shall I activate it somehow? (checked it it enabled in VS addins list)

Comment: Did you install it from Tools -> Extension Manager -> Online -> searching for its name?

Comment: I tried it now on a clean machine with extension manager and it seemed to work well for me.

Comment: I've installed that by double clicking on downloaded file. Will try uninstall it and let you know if works

Comment: Uninstalled and installed it via extension , but still doesnt work :( maybe because of collisions with ResharperI'm using

Comment: Good candidate. The machine I tried it on didn't have Resharper.
Did you try to change intellisense in Resharper to VS intellisense to confirm? (From Resharper Options -> Intellisense -> General -> Visual Studio) You should then still be able to trigger R# intellisense by CTRL+ALT+Space. Or the other way around, try triggering VS native intellisense using CTRL + J.

Comment: This Spell Checker is good for checking as you go, but is there a way to spell-check the whole file without manually looking at all of the lines? Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wholetomato.com%2F&ei=6WVWTZfjF4foOa7lnPQE&usg=AFQjCNFyQ2jQOEb8XQ-PgrDvV9KB6A3M0g&sig2=ACi3bS--kaYHZAU6JJE9sA) has nice spell checker for comments and strings, works in both C++ and C# (not sure about all the other languages).

It made me go over all the code in my current project and fix typos :)

Btw, I don't think spell checker for member names is a good idea. These are mostly composed of multiple concatenated words, shorthands etc.

Comment: I'm using Resharper so  VAX seems to be kind of duplication to me. Anyway (besides it is not free) it looks interesting.

Comment: @Maciej VA X works surprisingly well with Resharper. I use Resharper because it is superior to VA X in most aspects (in C#) and VA X for C++ and C++/CLI development (RS doesn't support C++). Sadly my VA X trial is ending soon and they don't seem to offer academic/open source license :(

Comment: VAX is heavily messing with intellisense and there is no way to stop it's intrusions to it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Resharper 4x, 5x this is also interesting (FREE) option

http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/

Agent Smith is C# code style validation plugin for ReSharper (Visual Studio plugin).

Current version includes following features:

```
* Naming convention validation.
* XML comment validation.
* XML comment, string literals, identifiers and resources (.resx files) spell checking
* Smart paste.
* XML comment reflowing.
```

Comment: I would switch to that, but I'm using Resharper 6.x and this seems doesnt work with it :(

Comment: looks like it's got resurrected - http://code.google.com/p/agentsmithplugin/downloads/list

Comment: Currently ReSharper provides three spell checkers. I'm using ReSpeller Free (http://etherealcode.com/respeller/). Not a big difference in compare to Agent Smith. Just a bit better look and added a settings page in ReSharper->Options. IMHO all spell checker fail when it comes to non en-US language and require a hack to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Found also this one (not tested yet):

http://code.google.com/p/vsspelleraddin/

```
Ability you to check spelling in selection in your Visual Studio files 
Provides a spell checking functionality for Visual Studio using Hunspell engine
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this is not supported anymore? I added the add-in files to one of Visual Studio's Add-In directories and restarted VS, but the add-in did not get loaded (vsspelleraddin is not shown in the Add-In Manager and I can't use the spell-check feature).